# angular 2 widget engine

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, widget

I am looking a Angular 2 Widgets to be dragged and dropped into the dashboard, lock and unlock it in place. I am looking for something similar to this:

https://github.com/rajeshvaya/angular-material-widget-engine

Seems like this only works with AngularJS not updated for Angular2. Anyone have any suggestions that could work with Angular2.

Thanks